# Error: no source files when using command substitution

Tags: bash, makefile, javac

I have the following code:

```
all: ./source/Listener.java ./source/ServerThread.java ./source/TestClient.java 
    javac -d target $(find ./source/* | grep .java)
```

When I run Make, I get this output

```
javac -d target
error: no source files
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I run the javac command in bash, it compiles fine. Furthermore, when I run the 'find' section, i get a list of files like I wanted. Additionally, the file paths in line 1 are all accurate.

Any tips?

(I have to use the find function because there are a lot of files in use, and it increases over time. I trimmed it down to 3, but the bug is still there anyway)

Comment: Which command do you want to execute in your "`all`" target ?

Comment: Replace `$(find ...)` in your recipe by `$$(find ...)` to escape the make expansion. As you wrote it make expands a make variable named `find ... .java`, which obviously does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RenaudPacalet said, I had to put an extra $ infront of the second line.

Comment: Using `find` in a rule is rather dubious in the first place. Probably use `javac -d target $$(find ./source/ -name '*.java')` if that's what you mean, or perhaps you simply mean `javac -d target ./source/*.java` without any need to recurse into subdirectories. But better still would be to declare explicit dependencies in your `Makefile` and let `make` figure out what to compile; that's what it's for.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute shell commands in a Makefile, use this syntax : `$(shell ...)`

Warnings :

- The default shell is `sh` (use `SHELL` macro definion to change it)

  - Example : `SHELL=/bin/bash`
- The dollar (`$`) symbol is special into Makefile and into bash script (if you want use it in shell script espace it with double dollar : `$$`).

  - Example: `$(shell X=a_value; echo $$a_value)`
  - If you want the current process of sub-shell : `$(shell echo $$$$)` ... ugly, no ?
- Do you want really call shell? It's not portable. Assume it.

If you search your sources files or what ever, use `wildcard` internal `make` function.

Examples:

```
all: x.class y.class z.class

x.class: a.java dir_b/b.java dir_c/c.java
    @echo "$$^=$^="
    @echo "not portable command ..." $(shell find . -name "*.java")

# Better with deps in target definition
SRCS=$(shell find . -name "*.java")
y.class: $(SRCS)
    @echo x_my_command $^

# Really better (portable)
SRCS=$(wildcard */*.java *.java)
z.class: $(SRCS)
    @echo y_my_command $^
```

Output:

```
$^=a.java dir_b/b.java dir_c/c.java=
not portable command ... ./dir_b/b.java ./dir_c/c.java ./a.java
x_my_command dir_b/b.java dir_c/c.java a.java
y_my_command dir_b/b.java dir_c/c.java a.java
```

Comment: There is no need to use the make `shell` function in a recipe. Recipes are already shell scripts. And what the OP want is to use shell commands in a recipe, nothing strange with this, it's absolutely normal.  And there is no need to change the default shell to `bash` to use `find`. There are several things that could be improved in the OP's Makefile (`find -name` instead of `find | grep`, `source/%.class: target/%.java` pattern rule...) but they have nothing to do with the question which is about the make expansion of recipes.

Comment: I want to be more strong: you should _never_ use `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe.  We should definitely not recommend that people do that in answers to questions.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet, @MadScientist: I always use `$ (shell ...)` to make an outside call to make. Explicitly seeing the differences with the built-in functions has always been essential. I have encountered the case of users calling standard or non-standard commands with the name `join`,` findstring` or `error`. Obviously, I can take it completely wrong, but I've never encountered a problem using `$ (shell ...)`